# Showing multiple customers for each order number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database for a fictitious company. This database has three tables: `customer`, `product`, and `orders`. For this query, I am only using two tables: `customer` and `orders`. I am trying to list all of the customers that have ordered items within the last 10 days, however, every time I run this code:

```
select concat(concat(customer.first_name, ' '), customer.last_name) as customer, orders.orderid, orders.productid, orders.order_date
from customer, orders
where orders.order_date > sysdate-10
order by orders.order_date;
```

I get a result that lists out each of the 6 customers with the same `ORDERID` number:

```
CUSTOMER                                       ORDERID  PRODUCTID ORDER_DATE
-------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Forrest Gump                                       113      20011 18-MAR-18
Bob Smith                                          113      20011 18-MAR-18
Michael Jordan                                     113      20011 18-MAR-18 
Sara Hamms                                         113      20011 18-MAR-18 
Joe Socks                                          113      20011 18-MAR-18`
Emma Bobleton                                      113      20011 18-MAR-18
Sara Hamms                                         114      20011 18-MAR-18 
Joe Socks                                          114      20011 18-MAR-18 
Michael Jordan                                     114      20011 18-MAR-18
Emma Bobleton                                      114      20011 18-MAR-18
Bob Smith                                          114      20011 18-MAR-18
CUSTOMER                                       ORDERID  PRODUCTID ORDER_DATE
-----------------------------------------   ---------- ---------- ----------
Forrest Gump                                       114      20011 18-MAR-18
Joe Socks                                          115      20010 19-MAR-18 
Sara Hamms                                         115      20010 19-MAR-18
Bob Smith                                          115      20010 19-MAR-18
Forrest Gump                                       115      20010 19-MAR-18 
Michael Jordan                                     115      20010 19-MAR-18 
Emma Bobleton                                      115      20010 19-MAR-18
Bob Smith                                          116      30001 19-MAR-18
Forrest Gump                                       116      30001 19-MAR-18
Michael Jordan                                     116      30001 19-MAR-18 
Sara Hamms                                         116      30001 19-MAR-18
CUSTOMER                                       ORDERID  PRODUCTID ORDER_DATE
------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Joe Socks                                          116      30001 19-MAR-18
Emma Bobleton                                      116      30001 19-MAR-18 

etc...
```

I want it to show the order associated with the customer like so:

```
CUSTOMER                                       ORDERID  PRODUCTID ORDER_DATE
------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Forrest Gump                                      113      20011 19-MAR-18
Forrest Gump                                      114      20011 19-MAR-18
Sara Hamms                                        115      20010 19-MAR-18
Emma Bobleton                                     116      30001 19-MAR-18
```

Would someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: you need to join the 2 tables. This is a cartesian product without the join

Comment: something like where order.user_id = users.user_id

Comment: Just FYI, this: `concat(concat(customer.first_name, ' '), customer.last_name)` can be rewritten as follows: `customer.first_name || ' ' || customer.last_name`. I'd also recommend putting a `TRIM()` around it in case one value or the other is `NULL`. Last, using table aliases is good, saves typing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comments state, you need to join the tables like the following

```
select concat(concat(customer.first_name, ' '), customer.last_name) as customer, orders.orderid, orders.productid, orders.order_date
from customer
JOIN orders ON orders.customerId = customer.id
where orders.order_date > sysdate-10
order by orders.order_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where maybe the folks who hate the older syntax and only want to see ANSI join syntax might have a point. If you had been using the "newer" ANSI join syntax this probably wouldn't have happened. This is what the query would look like with the older join syntax:

```
select concat(concat(customer.first_name, ' '), customer.last_name) as customer
     , orders.orderid, orders.productid, orders.order_date
  from customer, orders
 where customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id
   and orders.order_date > sysdate-10
 order by orders.order_date;
```

As I mentioned in my comment above the concatenation operator `||` is made just for these situations. Also, using table aliases can save you keystrokes. Last, please do learn the newer join syntax and use it:

```
SELECT TRIM(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) AS customer
     , o.orderid, o.productid, o.order_date
  FROM customer c INNER JOIN orders o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 WHERE o.order_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-10)
 ORDER BY order_date;
```

You'll also see that I applied a `TRUNC()` to your `SYSDATE-10`. Why? Because `SYSDATE` returns an Oracle `DATE` value which has a time portion. So if you're looking for orders over the past 10 days, and running your query at 7:00 pm on March 27, you'll only get orders from March 17 placed *after* 7:00 pm. (But maybe that's what you want!) By applying a `TRUNC()` you'll get orders starting at midnight on March 17.

Hope this helps.